# Acceder a una propiedad de la clase padre en la clase hija

Tags: c#, herencia

[image]
En la ventana izquierda esta la clase hija y la derecha la clase padre con la propiedad, no se si estoy confundido pero quiero llamar a los demas metodos que retornan valor numerico y restarlos con la propiedad pero me da error :(

Comment: Bienvenido. Carga el código como texto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base.Sueldo` es un propiedad no un método, quítale los paréntesis "()" cuando lo invoques.

Comment: gracias, la verdad si resolvi el problema pero hice un monton de modificaciones que esta confuso de explicar, mas con eso de crear objetos para las clases jaja